# What column-axis: vertical; does?

Tags: css, webkit

I am trying [CSS multi-columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) spec and came up with `column-axis`. But I don't understand what it does? It seems `column-axis: horizontal;` is *regular* CSS columns but I have no idea what `vertical` will do. In my testings it disabled columns altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the idea behind it is

> Allow “columns” to be stacked along the block axis rather than the inline axis.
>   This can facilitate
>   paginated interfaces. A column-axis property is added in order to enable this
>   mode.

per http://code.google.com/p/webkit-mirror/source/detail?r=ed6bd9e2ff389c57409a0808527e219b97b347b1

I may be wrong, but I suspect it isn't supported on any browser currently..